# In Python, using win32api doesn't set the correct date

Tags: python, windows, winapi, time

I am trying to set system date (not time) using following code. I want to set the current time  to the new date. Following is a sample code and I found the time is not correct after change.

```
day = 20
month = 3
year = 2010

timetuple = time.localtime()
print timetuple
print timetuple[3], timetuple[4], timetuple[5]
win32api.SetSystemTime(year, month, timetuple[6]+1, 
    day, timetuple[3], timetuple[4], timetuple[5], 1)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are setting the system time from the `localtime` timestamp. The latter is adjusted for the local timezone, while `SetSystemTime` [requires you to use the UTC timezone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Use [`time.gmtime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.gmtime) instead:

```
tt = time.gmttime()
win32api.SetSystemTime(year, month, 0, day, 
    tt.tm_hour, tt.tt_min, tt.tt_sec, 0)
```

You then also avoid having to deal with whether or not you are in summer time (DST) now, vs. March when you would be in winter time.

Alternatively you can use a [`datetime.datetime.utcnow()` call](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) and get the millisecond parameter as a bonus:

```
import datetime
tt = datetime.datetime.utcnow().time()
win32api.SetSystemTime(year, month, 0, day,
    tt.hour, tt.minute, tt.second, tt.microsecond//1000)
```

Note that I left the weekday item set to 0 in both examples; it is ignored when calling `SetSystemTime`. If it was *not* ignored, then your code example had the value wrong; the Python value ranges from 0 to 6 for Monday through to Sunday, while the Win32 API wants 1 through to 7 for *Sunday through to Saturday*. You'd have to add 2 and use modulo 7:

```
win32_systemtime_weekday = (python_weekday + 2) % 7)
```

Comment: This needs to be run with elevated permissions as normal users don't have access to change the system time.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Obviously that wasn't the problem; the wrong time was being set for the OP.

Comment: Yes but it is worth clarifying it.